# How do I view auditlogs from Dialogflow in gcp Logs

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-cloud-logging

I activated Audit logging for the Dialog API in my GCP Project, now i want to see if a new intent was added in the logs. But on the logging monitor is nothing

Answer (score 1):

I have enabled audit logging on my dialog flow and was able to successfully create logs in Stackdriver Logging. To do this I went on the gear menu next to my project ID > in the bottom of the General page checked the box in log settings that says: log interactions to Google Cloud.

I also had to refresh my service account access token in the same menu next to the service account name. the service account is also the log writer its possible that it's token is outdated.

Comment: thanks! i did this but i dont see anaything if i change somethink in a dialogflow agent. What do you see in your audit logs ?

Comment: When I enabled the feature I was able to make queries in the test function on right side panel and I would see some logs in Stackdriver saying the query was successfully delivered.p

Comment: Enabling the "Log interactions to Google Cloud" only adds log the queries and some debugging info. Unfortunately, it doesn't log config updates or changes made to the agent while using the website UI.